# referencing state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Keeping a reference to an specific (or "active") object is a pattern i use in many situations, to make changes to a specific object in an array of objects (or what have you).

```js
  state = {
  object1: { 'data': 'data1'},
  active_object: null,
}

// point active_object to object1
state.active_object = state.object1;

// modify it through the reference
state.active_object.data = 'data1modified';

// works as expected
console.log('object1.data: ' + state.object1.data);
```

Now the equivalent in a react component state would be something along theses lines (note that this is NON working tho). I suppose the reference gets lost "somewhere in translation". Is there a (*simple*) way to mimic the pattern above (other than restructuring, using object keys and such) to accomplish the same thing using react and state?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      active_object: null,
      object1: { 'data': 'data1'},
    }
  }

  modifyState() {
    // point active_object to object1 (using *functional* setState)
    this.setState((state) => (
      { active_object: state.object1 }
    ))

    // modify it through the reference (using *functional* setState)
    this.setState((state) => (
      { active_object: { ...state.active_object, ['data']: 'data1modified' } }
    ))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p onClick={ () => this.modifyState() }>modify</p>
        <p>{ this.state.object1.data }</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

EDIT: i've updated the example to use a constructor to not confuse people (i'm using babel, so not really needed in reality). Also, i've indicated more clearly in the comments that i'm using *functional* setState (also, to no confuse people). I need to clarify that i don't need help with getting this *particular* piece of code working, it's more about demonstrating what i would like to be *able* to do. In that regard, it pseudo-code even tho it actually works fine if you run it in react (other than that the reference gets lost, as expected).

EDIT2: As vs1682 point out in the comments to this question, the reference gets lost by using the objects spread operator when copying the object. So this problem isn't really react specific (only indirectly).

Comment: keeping a reference to a specific object is not a design pattern, it's simply a practice. Try to use `redux` for managing states. For fixing your issue add a `constructor` and set up your state there. Then use `setState` in order to update it in other methods of the class

Comment: `active_object: { ...state.active_object, ['data']: 'data1modified' }`. Here you are creating a whole new object by  `spreading` your `active_object` and adding a new property `data`. And thus you loose the reference.

Comment: @quirimmo thanks for the tip. I've been avoiding using redux this far since i really want to learn as much as i can about react before i move on to third party helpers and abstractions.

Comment: @vs1682 you seem to be correct! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an egregious typo, but you don't have a `constructor`. If you don't understand why you need one, maybe you should go back to basics and read up a bit on JavaScript ES6.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    active_object: null,
    object1: { 'data': 'data1'},
  }
}
```

`this.setState` does not accept a callback as its main argument... or at least this is not convention. `this.setState` can accept a callback as a secondary argument, but that is to handle the async nature of `this.setState`. It is not explicitly for changing state.

```
this.setState({ active_object: this.state.object1 })
```

Also, JavaScript convention highly encourages camelCase, not underscores.

edit: I was wrong. A function can be used in `this.setState`. In fact, it can be a pretty good idea.

Comment: re: your first point, It's possible they're using Babel's class properties, in which case a constructor isn't required. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties and https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus#property-initializers.

Comment: @essmahr Possible, yes, but still something to point out in case it's such an easy fix. I'm sure he/she will tell us if that's the case.

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear about that! I am indeed using babel's class properties. Being new to react (and js in general) i'm a little unclear on what is considered the norm and not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you that if you have references to properties *within the same object* (such as in the case in the question), you can perform a deep copy with for example [clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone). That will "relink" (i'm unsure of the terminology here) references even though a new object is returned with fresh content.

The only downside i see with this approach is that references that reach *outside* of the object you're cloning will not be preserved, whereas in a shallow copy (what you have with object spread or immutability-helper) it will, since it doesn't modify references at all. This specific gotcha might be related to [clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone) though.

Anyway, this works, but i have no idea of the performance implications, or if it even is good practice considering the functional nature of react and state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import clone from 'clone';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      activeObject: null,
      object1: { 'data': 'data1'},
    }
  }

  modifyState() {
    // point activeObject to object1
    this.setState((state) => {
      let newState = clone(state);
      newState.activeObject = newState.object1;
      return newState;
    })
    // modify it through the reference
    this.setState((state) => {
      let newState = clone(state);
      newState.activeObject.data = 'data1-modified';
      return newState;
  })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p onClick={ () => this.modifyState() }>modify</p>
        {/* will show 'data1-modified' after modifyState */}
        <p>{ this.state.object1.data }</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

It should probably be said that *cloning* objects with references is always tricky business, and requires more often then not that you set up a special method (specific for copying your object or data structure) than relying on shallow/deep copying alone. In my case, i think a "normal" shallow copy and a handler to restore references would be the best way to go.

Or, skip the reference altogether, and rely on unique object properties (such as and "active" identifier, or an "id") to replace the troublesome reference in this scenario. I suspect that in languages that rely on copy by value (and immutability) where the react model of immutable state comes from, this is less of a problem because of the lack (not always, but often) of object/value references.